# PowerShell SqlModule corrupted

Tags: powershell

I have installed `SqlServer` moduled with `Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Repository PSGallery -Verbose` command. PS says that it was successfuly.

But when I'm runneng `import-module` I only see 3 items imported from this module:

```
PS >import-module sqlserver -erroraction stop -verbose
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sqlserver\21.0.17240\sqlserver.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Populating RepositorySourceLocation property for module sqlserver.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Program 
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\sqlserver\21.0.17240\SqlServer.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'SQLSERVER:'.
VERBOSE: Exporting alias 'Encode-SqlName'.
VERBOSE: Exporting alias 'Decode-SqlName'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'SQLSERVER:'.
VERBOSE: Importing alias 'Decode-SqlName'.
VERBOSE: Importing alias 'Encode-SqlName'.
```

Question: how to get all the commands (like `Invoike-Sqlcmd` and other) from `SqlServer` working?

PS Version

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                 
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.251                                                                                                                                                                                         
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                               
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                               
BuildVersion                   10.0.16299.251                                                                                                                                                                                        
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                       
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                   
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                   
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

UPDATE:

Running `Get-Command -Module SqlServer | Measure` gives even after force reinstall with `Install-Module SqlServer -Force`:

```
PS H:\> Get-Command -Module SqlServer | Measure

Count    : 3
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Checked event log. Found bunch of `Information` records, when importing the `SqlServer` module like this:

```
Context Information: 
    DetailSequence=1
    DetailTotal=1

    SequenceNumber=17

    UserId=DOMAIN/User
    HostName=ConsoleHost
    HostVersion=5.1.16299.251
    HostId=GUID
    HostApplication=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
    EngineVersion=5.1.16299.251
    RunspaceId=GUID
    PipelineId=6
    ScriptName=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.0.17240\SqlServer.psm1
    CommandLine=        Add-Type -Path $binaryPath


Details: 
CommandInvocation(Add-Type): "Add-Type"
ParameterBinding(Add-Type): name="Path"; value="C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.0.17240\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.dll"
```

Comment: If you run ```Get-Command -Module SqlServer | Measure```, you should get about 98-commands. What do you get? You can try to re-install the module (```Install-Module SqlServer -Force```) Then try to load it again. I pulled the module down today, and I'm not having the problem you described.

Comment: Only 3.The command output in the question update.
End even after force reinstall, output remains the same. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Okay do this...

1. Find all your various module folders -- you can use the following to do this:

   $env:PSModulePath.Split(';')
2. Removing the "sqlserver" folder from each directory, if it exists.
3. Re-import the module.

   Install-Module -Name SqlServer -AllowClobber

Steps-1 and -2 make sure there are no mangled `SqlServer` module installations lurking anywhere. Step-3 gives us a fresh pull of the module.

The only thing I can think of. Maybe there is a mangled module installed somewhere. It isn't getting overwritten during re-install, but it's accidentally getting loaded.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately didn't helped. The only folder I have found was: `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\` and after reistall it was recreated. And it still exports only 3 items: that are defined in `SqlServerPostScript.ps1`. But it looks like PS ignores items that defined in `CmdletsToExport` property in `SqlServer.psd1` file. Event though `Import-Module -Verbose -Name SqlServer` shows that it loads it. BTW. Last command shows that it loads from `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.0.17240\` path.

Comment: Rats! What edition/version OS you running? I'm testing this on a Windows 10 64-bit machine.

Comment: It's Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit.

Comment: Man, I’m drawing a blank. I tried to recreate this a few different ways, but can’t. Anything unusual about your environment?

Comment: Not of anything I'm aware of. I'm developer, so I have VS, .Net Core and SQL Server installed.
Also this question is confituation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359773/backup-sqldatabase-is-not-recognized as I realized bigger issue.