# Importing Posh-ssh moudle in powershell does not import all cmdlets

Tags: powershell, posh-ssh

I am trying to import posh-ssh moudle to upload files to sftp server. I cannot install module in my windows server 2012 R2. Hence i used save-module in my local system and tried to import the module in the server. It imports few cmdlets but does not import the rest which i require to upload files to sftp.

Missing cmdlets 
Get-SFTPFile Set-SFTPFile New-SFTPSession

[image]

Comment: How are you importing the module?  It looks like you may have dot sourced a few of the cmdlets but not the module itself

Comment: Oleg Oshkoderov reported a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177867/powershell-sqlmodule-corrupted?noredirect=1#comment87434113_50177867. I don't think we ever figured out the issue. If you find a fix, let him know.

Comment: @BryceMcDonald Yes you were right. I imported the module using .psm1 file instead of .psd1 file

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to import the module by importing .psm1 file which did not include all the cmdlets . When i imported using .psd1 file , it include all the cmdlets from the module.

[image]